# category & sub category order issues in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting, categories

I have Two parent category on my website, and each of those category have children category, like this :

- constructions corollaires
- - 01
- - 02
- - 03
- - 04
- Between two suns
- - I
- - II
- - III
- - IV

I'm trying to display the parent category on a archive page, and also the children category.

here is my code for the parent category :

```
<?php 

    $category = get_the_category(); 
    echo $category[0]->name;

?>
```

and for the children category :

```
<?php 

    $category = get_the_category(); 
    echo $category[1]->name;

?>
```

what I don't understand, is that for posts who are in inside "Between two suns" category, first code echoes "Between two suns" which is the correct value, but posts who are inside "constructions corollaires", it echoes "I", the sub category instead of "constructions corollaires".

and it's the same problem with my second code, for posts who are in inside "Between two suns" category, second code echo "I" which is the correct value (1st children category), but posts who are inside "constructions corollaires", it echoes "constructions corollaires", the parent category instead of "01" for example (the children category.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong...

all my categories are sorted in the back end.

can anybody help me with this ? It looks like an ordering issue but I really don't know how to fix this !

Answer (score 0):

**For only Top label category**

```
$categories = get_terms( 
'category', 
 array('parent' => 0)
);
```

**And get children category just pass parent category id in parent item**

```
$categories = get_terms( 
'category', 
array('parent' => $cat->ID)
);
```

Comment: thanks @omar faruque, I tried with your answer, but I still get the same issue...
first code returns parent cat when parent category is "Between two suns" but children cat when parent is "constructions corollaires"
and second code  returns children cat when parent category is "Between two suns" but parent cat when parent is "constructions corollaires"

I think the problem comes from my category order inside the back end... can you help me with this ?

Comment: With fist code you can get all of your top label category, is it work?

Comment: no its not, I get parent cat for all posts who are inside the parent cat "Between two suns", but Children post when posts are inside the parent cat "constructions corollaires"... and the opposite when using the second code

Comment: Do you need category listing or post listing?

Comment: category listing. the two codes you gave me are supposed to work. But I think the issue comes from my category ordering and hiearchy. any ideas ?

Comment: If you think it's order problem, you can use a order plugin, and can change your order from backend, you can use it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/